# Where is wrong in my SQLite expression?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO pattent VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" %(PattentNumber,PattentName,PattentInventors,PattentCompany,PattentFiledtime,PattentAbstract))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error
```

Above is my INSERT sentence.
It works fine with other cases but it says that `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error`

I use Python and all the VALUES is text.
Where is worng?

Thank you!

Comment: Likely the error is that your text includes apostrophe s:  "It's".  The apostrophe ends the SQL string literal, and the s is a syntax error.  Using parameters as Martijn suggests will solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *not* use string formatting, use SQL parameters instead:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO pattent VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    (PattentNumber, PattentName, PattentInventors, PattentCompany, PattentFiledtime, PattentAbstract))
```

SQL parameters make sure your values are escaped *correctly*, prevent SQL injection attacks and handle different types properly.